# How can I emit delimited text (like CSV) from Jq?

Tags: csv, jq

When using Jq for data processing, it's often more convenient to emit the processed text in some kind of "delimited" form that other CLI tools can consume, such as Awk, Cut, and the `read` builtin in Bash.

Is there a straightforward way to achieve this?

Sample data:

```
[
  {"a": 11, "b": 12, "c": 13},
  {"a": 21, "b": 22, "c": 23},
  {"a": 31, "b": 32, "c": 33},
  {"a": 41, "b": 42, "c": 43}
]
```

Desired output:

```
a,c
11,13
21,21
31,33
41,43
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jq --raw-output 'map({ a, c }) | ( .[0] | keys_unsorted), (.[] | [.[]]) | @csv'
```

Will produce:

```
"a","c"
11,13
21,23
31,33
41,43
```

---

[Online JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/nSmcvPlvNS)

Answer (score -2):

If you can assume that the attribute names are the same in all array elements, you can use the `@csv` formatter along with `--raw-output`:

Put this in a script like `json-records-to-csv.jq`, adjusting the shebang as needed:

```
#!/usr/bin/jq --raw-output -f

# Like `keys`; extracts object values as an array.
def values:
    to_entries | map(.value)
;

# Get the column names from the first array element keys
(.[0] | keys | @csv)
,
# Get the values from every array element values
(.[] | values | @csv)
```

Usage example:

```sh
json-records-to-csv.jq <<'JSON'
[
  {"a": 11, "b": 12, "c": 13},
  {"a": 21, "b": 22, "c": 23},
  {"a": 31, "b": 32, "c": 33},
  {"a": 41, "b": 42, "c": 43}
]
JSON
```

Output:

```
"a","b","c"
11,12,13
21,22,23
31,32,33
41,42,43
```